# How can I attach and remove randomly EventListener

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

as the title, I dont want to attach listener for all child nodes, I just want to attach and remove listener for some of them. how can I do that. As I know, if we want to remove the listener, we have to named it, but in this situation we can not named all of listeners. example for this situation:

```
ROOT
  ---1
      ---A
      ---B
      ---C
      ---More here
  ---2
      ---D
      ---E
      ---F
      ---More here
```

I just want to attach and remove listener for A, C or some other nodes. not all of them. How to do that ?

Update : this is the database and the code I am using, but I just want to attach and remove listener from some specific nodes, not all of them. hope this helps.

[image]

```
 GlobalConstants.ROOT_REF.child("USERS")
                .orderByChild("active").equalTo("online")
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                        // update status here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                                // update status here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: How about adding a listener only on those specific nodes? What have tried so far in code?

Comment: I attached listener to the root node, currently. I have no idea about attaching and removing listener with specific nodes. Because the number of node is unlimited and random

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and a screenshot of your database structure and please also indicate which is the exact particular node/nodes that you want to listen to.

Comment: I am having dinner right now, I will post my code as soon as possible. Thanks